# Function name changed in library

Tags: c++

I have a small query as below.

I have created a shared library from below code.

**help.h**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void killMe(int sig_num);

void printMe(void);
```

**help.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void killMe(int sig_num)
{
    cout<<"Timeout occurred."<<endl;
    raise(SIGKILL);
}

void printMe()
{
    cout<<"This is help.cpp"<<endl;
}

[root@localhost DL]# nm -n /usr/local/lib/libmyhelp.so | grep " T "
00000584 T _init
00000760 T _Z6killMei
000007ae T _Z7printMev
00000864 T _fini
[root@localhost DL]#
```

Checking the output of nm, i see that killMe and printMe functions' names have been changed a little. Is there any way to retain the same name in shared library as it is in cpp code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B). To turn it off, declare the functions as `extern "C"`.

**help.h:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" {

void killMe(int sig_num);

void printMe(void);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I did the code changes as suggested but its still not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `extern "C"` to the implementations, too, it should work. The help.h file doesn't take part in the compilation process. However, there's a better way: `#include "help.h"` as first line in the cpp file, which verifies it can be included by itself and that the definitions for the functions declared in the header file match.

Some more notes:

- You lack include guards.
- The void to mark an empty parameter list is redundant in C++, though not in C.
- I'd call the header file help.hpp in order to make clear it's C++.
- You could also remove the iostream include and then make it compatible to C. You would then have to handle the case that exceptions are thrown from the C++ code, which must not happen for use in C.

Comment: Thanks doomster. I understood that help.h wasn't taking part in compilation process as i haven't included it in help.cpp. Doing so got me the required output from nm command. Thanks once again.